# How to run a target only it hasn't run?

Tags: msbuild

I have a NAnt script like below:

```
<target name="Init" unless="${target::has-executed('Init')}">
```

What I want is to convert it into MSBuild script. What I can't do is to write MSBuild script to run a target only when it hasn't run like the above script.

Please help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Targets only run [once](http://blogs.msdn.com/msbuild/archive/2007/11/14/what-are-targets-tasks-and-tools.aspx) in an MSBUild build process. So just have a CallTarget element, and if it's already run, it will be skipped.